# Creating Rich Text Field via Core Service

Tags: 2011, core-service

When saving to a rich text field via Core Service my HTML is not as desired. During create tags like:

```
<a id="abc" name="abc"></a>
```

become:

```
<a id="abc" name="abc"/>
```

I have added to the XSLT to try and prevent this:

```
<template match="a[(@name) and (count(node()) = 0)]">
   <copy>
      <apply-templates select="@*"></apply-templates>
      <span class="hidden"></span>
   </copy>
</template>
```

but no joy!

It seems to apply the base XSLT when creating via Core Service. Then if I open the component and make any changes my updated XSLT appies and the HTML updates to:

```
<a id="abc" name="abc">
   <xhtml:span xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="hidden"></xhtml:span>
</a>
```

Comment: What is going on with your namespaces there? if the default namespace is for xsl, then why do you get xhtml:span ?

Answer (score 4):

I've just written a quick script that creates a component via the core service. FWIW, the powershell exposes ComponentData.Content as a string, and I just shoved in something like:

```
<Content xmlns="uuid:985d42e5-976f-46e1-9727-772cb961353f">
<NewField></NewField>
</Content>
```

This showed up exactly like that in the component.

I wouldn't expect the RTF XSLT to modify the content when written via the core service (or TOM.NET or any other API. The XSLT cleanup is a GUI operation, albeit these days implemented via a back-end service. If you create content via code, it's on you to send clean data. Obviously, when you open the component up in the GUI, the slightest modification will cause the XSLT to fire.

So to summarise: it doesn't look like the data goes via an XML document to get across the wire to the core service. (Mind you, I'm using nettcp = hope /that/ abstraction isn't leaking!) Usually when `<x></x>` gets transformed to `<x/>` it's because the document has been deserialised to the infoset representation. So does your implementation load this into a DOM?

Edit: Per your comment suggestion, I altered my input. I had to put the p in the xhtml namespace, and provide a closing

, but on opening via the gui, I found this in the source.

```
<Content xmlns="uuid:985d42e5-976f-46e1-9727-772cb961353f">
<NewField>
  <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">this is a test <a name="abc" id="abc"></a></p>
</NewField>
</Content>
```

... so still, the conclusion remains that it may not be the core service that is collapsing your elements.

Further edit:

In the source tab of the RTF I get: 
    `<p>this is a test <a name="abc" id="abc"/></p>`

Comment: Is NewField of type RTF? If so add <Content xmlns="uuid:985d42e5-976f-46e1-9727-772cb961353f">
<NewField><p  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">this is a test <a name="abc" id="abc"></a></NewField>
</Content>

Comment: If it behaves as per my implementation you will end up with <p xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml">this is a test <a name="abc" id="abc" /></p> at publish/preview time

Comment: I've updated, my answer. I note that you mention publish/preview time. What do you see when you open up the component in the GUI? Could it be a templating issue?

Comment: Thanks for checking this out! Is this the "source" tab of the component? What do you see in the "source" tab of the rich text field?

Comment: I see that my component.Content before CoreService.Create has the closing anchor tag, and immediately after it does not have closing anchor.

Comment: If I put <a id="abc" name="abc"> </a> then it persists. The space counts as some content in the tag

Comment: There is no processing on RTF field in template. Just output. The closing tag is missing in the GUI on the RTF source tab

Comment: As you can see in my "Further edit", there's no content between the opening and closing tags which might prevent an XML representation from compacting it to a self-closing tag. This looks like the core service really treats it as a string all the way.

Comment: So this is the problem. When you take this to the browser <a name="abc" id="abc"/> is treated as an opening anchor tag

Comment: The XSLT applied to the RTF when it is created via Core Service appears to not be the same as the XSLT applied if you edit it via the GUI. If I edit via GUI any modification I make to the RTF XSLT is applied e.g. adding nbsp or span tag. When created through Core Service the modified XSLT does not seem to apply and empty tags are short circuited to <a/> etc

Comment: As far as I know, there is no "other" XSLT. There's the RTF "filtering" XSLT, which is used by the GUI, and not by the API. Anyway, in general, it's not XSLT that compacts your tags, but the fact of loading it into a DOM representation. But you shouldn't really worry too much about it. If your site design demands the "verbose" format for a tag, then make sure that's what your templates output.